# how to add text within the center of each color?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9PT5.png)The goal is to add text in the middle of each color bar. The course made us refactor our code using functions. The way it was before, I was able to add text easily. Now that the code has been refactored, I've been having trouble figuring out how to add the text. Here is the refactored code.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void buttonSound(int noteNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$noteNumber.wav');
  }

  Expanded buildKey({Color color, int noteNumber, String text}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        color: color,
        onPressed: () {
          buttonSound(noteNumber);
        },
        child: null,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildKey(color: Colors.red, noteNumber: 1),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blue, noteNumber: 2),
              buildKey(color: Colors.orangeAccent, noteNumber: 3),
              buildKey(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, noteNumber: 4),
              buildKey(color: Colors.lightGreen, noteNumber: 5),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blueGrey, noteNumber: 6),
              buildKey(color: Colors.lime, noteNumber: 7),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Refactoring to use functions doesn't change the way you would display the text. It just changes the location in the code where you do that display.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass in text to `buildKey`

```dart
Expanded buildKey({Color color, int noteNumber, String text}) {
  return Expanded(
    child: FlatButton(
      color: color,
      onPressed: () {
        buttonSound(noteNumber);
      },
      child: Text(text),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I'm still having errors though.

I added ```child: Text(text), ```

I added text like this ```buildKey(color: Colors.red, noteNumber: 1, text: 'Text'),```

I then receive this error code:
The following assertion was thrown building XylophoneApp(dirty):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

Answer (score 0):

In your `buildKey` add a child of `Center` and `Text`:

```
 Expanded buildKey({Color color, int noteNumber, String text}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        color: color,
        onPressed: () {
          buttonSound(noteNumber);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And then, when you call the `buildKey`, make sure to add the `text` parameter to all of it:

```
children: <Widget>[
              buildKey(color: Colors.red, noteNumber: 1, text: 'Note 1'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blue, noteNumber: 2, text: 'Note 2'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.orangeAccent, noteNumber: 3, text: 'Note 3'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, noteNumber: 4, text: 'Note 4'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.lightGreen, noteNumber: 5, text: 'Note 5'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blueGrey, noteNumber: 6, text: 'Note 6'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.lime, noteNumber: 7, text: 'Note 7'),
            ],
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: It worked! At first first, I added the child of center, text widget and one text parameter (to 'Note 1') to test it out. It crashed the app and wouldn't work. I looked at my code to see what was going wrong and didn't see nothing. I re-read your post where it says 'make sure to add the text parameter to 'ALL' of it. The 'ALL' part made the difference. I added the 'text :' on the rest of the buildKey function calls with empty strings to test it out and saw the centered text, thank you!

Comment: Okay. Then please close this question by accepting the answer. It's my pleasure to help you. Happy developing.